# "Anti-PF1 monoclonal antibody" vs. "Monoclonal anti-PF1 antibody": order of adjectives

Tags: adjective-order

Which is better:

1. "Anti-PF1 monoclonal antibody"
2. "Monoclonal anti-PF1 antibody"?

I think it's the second: **monoclonal anti-PF1 antibody**, because "anti-PF1" expresses purpose.

I've read about [order of adjectives](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order) on the Cambridge.org site, and it looks like option 2 is better.

Comment: Since "monoclonal antibody" is a recognized class of antibody and "anti-PF1" describes a special behavior that one such antibody has, I'd go with the first, which keeps "monoclonal antibody" intact as the primary noun phrase and makes "anti-PF1" adjectival.

Comment: Compare: **anti-rust acrylic paint**, which is more natural than "acrylic anti-rust paint".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - but "monoclonal" is not the basic property of "antibody", it's just one of the ways of raising an antibody. Polyclonal antibodies are produced by different B cells and react with different epitopes, while monoclonal are from the same lineage, and react to the same epitope. I can look at the issue both ways, and one second I feel like option 1 is better, the other second I feel that option 2 is better.

Comment: But "monocolonal antibody" is an *established* noun-phrase / collocation.

Comment: You say **therapeutic monoclonal antibodies** not "monoclonal therapeutic antibodies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have been constantly hearing news about advances with **monoclonal antibodies** for the last thirty-five years, you won't really have the sense that the phrase **monocolonal antibody** has become an "established" collocation, which trumps any order-of-adjectives decision you might want to make. The phrase remains intact.

If you take a look at [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monoclonal%20*%20antibodies&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cmonoclonal%20%2A%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20IgM%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20hybridoma%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20antireceptor%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20mouse%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20IgG%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20antimelanoma%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20primary%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20antiidiotypic%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20antitumor%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmonoclonal%20antitubulin%20antibodies%3B%2Cc0), which lists the top instances of **monoclonal {something} antibodies**, you will see that it is only early in the scientific development of these therapies that the phrase is split by an adjective. Once the term **monoclonal antibody** becomes established, the practice falls off precipitously.